# How to disable link in telephone phone number in address book?

Tags: magento2.2, customer-address, address, link, styles

Using magento 2.2, I want to remove link from **phone number** in address book. Not allow user click on number.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it easily from backend

**Admin > STORES > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer configuration > Address Templates > HTML**

Replace HTML field content line with below

```
{{depend telephone}}T: <a href="tel:{{var telephone}}">{{var telephone}}</a>{{/depend}}
```

to

```
{{depend telephone}}T: <span>{{var telephone}}</span>{{/depend}}
```

save and flush cache you will see your desired result in admin order view page.

For Frontend Shipping address section you need to rewrite below template in your theme

**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html**

Add above default.html file to below location

**app/design/frontend/VendoreName/ThemeName/Magento_Checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-address/address-renderer/default.html**

Comment: It work in address book. But not work with 'Shipping Address'. Prashant Valanda.

Comment: on frontend? its not working?

Comment: On front-end. In **Check Out** step 'Shipping Address' still display.

Comment: @BongChannarith updated answer please check it